# Can you change the timestep interval in the dhtmlx scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dhtmlx-scheduler

Is it possible to change the time step in the [dhtmlx-scheduler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) so that it increments by 15 minutes instead of 1 hour? Have not found anything in the documentation or by exploring the code.

I am using the .Net version of the library.

[image: change time step]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the scale step, but you can define a custom template for the scale, and render smaller time units.

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/sizing.html#howtochangethescalespacing